# How can I output the student name before a desired value?

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

Ok, Guys, I'm very confused as to how I can create this program. I have a good piece  of it written however I have hit a standstill in which I do not know I can make this happen. So is this the following I assignment I have to do.

Assignment:
Download the file gradeBook.txt available through D2l. The file contains an unknown number of
students.

this is whats in the text file:

Melanie
84
Danielle Marie
90
Nicolas Raul
87
Michael
67
Joshua
46
Alexis Michelle
90
Jared M.
55
Andres Gabriel
78
Pierre Louis
80
Charles
60
Cin Lian
95
Carlos Manuel
81

Information for each student is displayed in two lines:

 The first line indicates the name of the student – whitespaces are allowed.

 The second line shows the student’s grade in a class.
Write a program that prompts the user for the name of the file and displays a nicely formatted
report showing:

a. Student with the highest grade in the class – Name and grade

b. Student with the lowest grade in the class – Name and grade

c. Average grade in the class

here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    fstream gFile;
    int choice, grades;
    string gb,students;
    do {
        cout << "Student Grade Book Info Program....\n";
        cout << "\tPlease Select an Option: (1 or 2) \n" << endl
            << "\t1. Review Grades"
            << "\n\t2. Quit"
            << "\n\tChoose: ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice) {

        case 1: 
            cout << "\n\tPlease Enter the Name of the File you wish to View the Grades for: " << endl;
            cout << "\n\tAvailable Grade Books: gradeBook\n" <<
            "\tType in the Grade Book you would like to view. ";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, gb);

            if (gb == "gradeBook") {

                gFile.open("gradeBook.txt", ios::in);

                if (gFile) {

                    cout << "\t" << setw(20) << left << "Student"
                        << setw(30) << left << "Grade";

                    int counter = 0;
                    int highest = 0;
                    while (gFile >> students) {

                        getline(gFile, students);
                        gFile >> grades;

                        if (grades >= highest) {
                            highest = grades;
                        }
                        counter++;
                    }
                    cout << highest;
                    cout << endl;
                }
                else {
                    cout << "\tError... Could open gradeBook.txt ";
                    return 5;
                }

            }
            else {
                cout << "\n\tError there is no such entry in the system.\n" << endl;

            }

        case 2:
            break;
        }

    } while (choice != 2);


    return 0;
}
```

I need to display the highest grade which I was able obtain and display it, but how can I display the name thats before the grade value in the gradeBook.txt file?

Please help me anyone? I'm so confused???

Comment: How about have two appropriately sized arrays - one of type int and one of type string.  Then read in the entire txt file with getline, etc. alternately pushing the name string and int to their appropriate arrays with the same index number.  Then the averaging and who got highest or lowest will be much easier.  Make any sense.

Comment: Also you have the student name in students before you grab their grade. Add a new variable called highestStudent and update it in the same spot you upgrade highest. Though I do think the array solution is more eloquent.

Comment: The thing is @Chris I can't use arrays, We haven't "Covered" arrays in class so the thing I can use is either dowhile, while or for loops

Comment: Yep, that makes it much more difficult. Alright, let me have a look again.

Comment: @Chris Thank you, I'm pretty damn confused???

Comment: There is no need for an array. But consider some simpler problems: suppose I gave you a file containing a lot of numbers (separated by spaces), and asked you to write code to read the file and print the numbers one by one. If you see how to do that, suppose I asked to print only the highest number. Then consider how to scan the file you were given, and print each name followed by the corresponding grade. Then only the student with the highest grade. How far can you get?

Comment: @VictorMartins See my answer for completed solution.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're still stuck. As an exercise, modify for 2 students with same grade... ;)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main() {
    int choice, intBuffer, subtotalGrades, countGrades,
         average, highGrade, lowGrade = 100;
    choice = intBuffer = subtotalGrades = countGrades = average = highGrade = 0;
    std::string nameBuffer, studentHigh, studentLow;

    cout << "\tStudent Grade Book Info Program....\n";
    cout << "\tPlease Select an Option: (1 or 2) \n" << "\n"
        << "\t1. Review Grades"
        << "\n\t2. Quit"
        << "\n\tChoose: ";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 2) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        std::ifstream gFile("gradeBook.txt", std::ios::in);
        if (!gFile) {
            cout << "\tError... Could not open gradeBook.txt\n";
            return 1;
        }
        while (gFile) {
            gFile.ignore();
            getline(gFile, nameBuffer);
            gFile >> intBuffer;
            if (intBuffer > highGrade) {
                highGrade = intBuffer;
                studentHigh = nameBuffer;
            }
            else if (intBuffer < lowGrade) {
                lowGrade = intBuffer;
                studentLow = nameBuffer;
            }
            subtotalGrades += intBuffer;
            countGrades++;
        }
        gFile.close();
    }
    average = subtotalGrades / countGrades;

    // Report section.
    cout << "\t" << std::setw(20) << "Student" << std::setw(30) << "Grade" << "\n";
    cout << "\t" << std::setw(20) << studentHigh << std::setw(30) << highGrade << "\n";
    cout << "\t" << std::setw(20) << studentLow << std::setw(30) << lowGrade << "\n";
    cout << "\t" << std::setw(20) << "Average" << std::setw(30) << average << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ohh wow, I had figured it how to obtain the lowest value of both but not how to display the names! This really helps, I had no idea I could use the ignore() function with the a file, how is that possible, ow do I know a function like ignore will work that way?

Comment: Hey Chris would you be able to explain what exactly does ignore() does???

Comment: The call gFile >> intBuffer leaves a newline character "\n" in the ifstream object.  The gFile.ignore() removes it.  Placed at top of loop, but could also have been placed directly after the gFile >> intBuffer call.  Look at http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/  Cplusplus.com is an important resource.

Comment: Thank very much, This was a great explanation, much appreciate it. Ill look into it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the information in your program.

Hint:  You only need to store the following:

- Highest grade value
- Student name with highest grade value
- Lowest grade value
- Student name with lowest grade value
- Sum of grades (used by average)
- Quantity of grades (used by average)

Here's the algorithm:

```
While reading name and grade succeeds do:
  compare to highest value -- if greater, replace highest grade with new grade
  compare to lowest value -- if lower, replace lowest grade with new grade.
  increment number of grades
  add grade to sum.
```

Remember to replace the name along with the grade value.

If you need more help, try searching the internet "stackoverflow c++ highest grade average".